# Why is there an older version of my local home sdk installed on my google nest hub?

Tags: sdk, nest, devtools

Upon uploading new bundle.js files and rebooting my google nest hub, I notice it is running an older local home sdk version.

My flow: I upload the two bundle.js files on the console actions page. Save. Then, I restart my google nest hub.
I open chrome://inspect/#devices. I see my device and I click on Inspect. In DevTools, I see the console log from my device.

In my code I always update the version so that I can easily see the version in the console log.
Sometimes the newest version is present (let's say 0.0.2).
Very often, I upload a newer version (let's say 0.0.3) and suddenly I see version 0.0.1.
Were does this version come from? Why isn't the newest version on the device?

How do I solve this? How can I make sure, every time I reboot my nest hub, it downloads the latest version?